# jquery display submenu while Moushover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal menu. This sub menu is displayed outside the ul. When i hover on a specific class, I want the .sub_menu to appear. When I hover the .sub_menu, I want it to be still there.

However, when moving my mouse from to the .sub_menu, it disappears.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () {
        jQuery(this).siblings('.sub-menu').slideFadeToggle();
        if (jQuery(this).find('i').hasClass('icon-angle-down')) {
            jQuery(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-angle-down');
            jQuery(this).find('i').addClass('icon-angle-up');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-angle-up');
            jQuery(this).find('i').addClass('icon-angle-down');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Where's the `'mouseover'`? Looks like a click to me. `'mouseenter'` is what you want anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mobile-sub-menu-controller', function () { ..
```

change click to `'mouseenter'`, because `'mouseover'` will trigger the event for every movement unit the cursor moves across the target.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can attach watcher for both elements (menu item and submenu) and decide with class you should use in both watchers.

However, is your menu has the structure like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><i>icon<i> Text
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><i>icon<i> Text
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
<ul>
```

You can use css or mouseenter/mouseleave events to toggle the menu item class to show submenu.

Be careful, if there is a gap between menu item and submenu your css or js will work incorrectly because mouse will leave menu item to the another element but not to the submenu.

If you have some additional information or questions let me know.

Also you may attach your menu html code to clarify the question.